# Show that $\frac{\delta L}{\delta v^2}$ be constant?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given
$$2 \vec{\varepsilon }\cdot\frac{\delta L}{\delta v^2}\frac{d \vec{r}}{dt} = \frac{dg(\vec{r},t)}{dt}$$
with $\vec{\varepsilon }\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is infinitesimal small vector, $\vec{r}=\vec{r}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$, $L = L(v^2)$ a function of $v^2$, and $g(\vec{r},t)$ an arbitrary total differentiable function of time $t$.

show that $\frac{\delta L}{\delta v^2}$ be constant.

I just apply chain rule: $\frac{dg(\vec{r},t)}{dt} = \frac{dg}{d\vec{r}}\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$ but see nothing.

Comment: One word; the symbol for partial derivatives is $\partial$(partial).

Comment: if $\vec\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}^3$ then it cannot be infinitesimal

Comment: @Masacroso, why? here, it's mean $||\varepsilon||\rightarrow 0$. Of course, for rigorous, we need limit with $\epsilon, \delta$